# How to execute a script on gdm login automatically for all users?

Tags: centos, login, gdm, hook

What file should I modify to execute some instructions when any user logs in through gdm?

I tried `/etc/bashrc` but that is executed ony when starting bash (and each time an xterm is open). I'd like to execute something only once when the user logs in.

What I want to do is to "reset" some user preferences each time the user logs on (including the window manager), so the script should run before the WM is initialized.

Comment: Why do you want to annoy your users like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution that seems to work best for me is to edit `/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default`. This is executed just after the user logs in with gdm. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian and derivatives you can modify `/etc/profile`, don't think it is universal, though.

Comment: This is only for shell logins - and the OP pointed he was not interested in such solution.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: this also works for GDM logins, because it reads `/etc/profile` (see `/etc/gdm/Xsession`). There is not a general rule for all DMs, I think.

Comment: Hm... Maybe it is, I don't know - but did you check _when else_ it is sourced? One can do some testing of the login setup of course, but then you should describe this approach more.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and  executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

For change the WM of your users: uninstall kdm/gdm/xdm/slim, setup the WM in ~/.xinitrc and run "startx" from your bash config.